# Howto check, is transparent proxy refers to dead server?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I'm using server objects via Remoting.

On client I get and keep reference to Transparent Proxy, representing remote object.

But when remote server is "dead" (closed, hang), I'd like to detect it via my proxy reference.

Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve that is to implement a `Ping()` method. I've implemented my own monitoring thread to keep track of live vs dead clients but you could do the same on the client to monitor the server.

Both the client and server implementations could have this `Ping()` method.

```
try{
  server.Ping();
}
catch( RemotingException re){
    //99% sure it's a dead or unreachable...
}
```

The implementation is nothing:

```
public void Ping() { }
```

Comment: Thanks, but are there ways other than pinging?

Comment: I was hoping, that .Net Remoting support it on it's side.

Comment: no, it doesn't, you have to maintain the connection.

Comment: maintain is the wrong word, you have to monitor the health of the connection.